# Nothing happens on clicking links in chrome browser opened by Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have some code written in selenium and using chrome driver. I am able to successfully run it and complete my flow when I run it from my system.

But, the flow fails when I try to run it from a remote system. I have the same selenium libraries and the same version of chrome browser and driver installed on the remote system as well.

The exact issue is that selenium opens the application and clicks on a link from a menu drop down. But nothing seems to be happening after it clicks. Nothing happens even when I try to click on the links on the selenium opened browser manually after the flow fails.

But everything works when I try to launch the browser manually from the same remote machine.

Please let me know what could the issue.

Comment: Could you please give more info on what kind of application you are working on and does it need any services to running background and all that

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you are probably running selenium 3.x and probably triggering through selenium remote server, try setting up the flag 'enablePassThrough' to 'false' like this,

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver.exe -jar "selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar" -enablePassThrough false
```

More details here - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ef44fef13349251c410a0d5357b8cd237a122f06/java/CHANGELOG#L20